# Android Universal ImageLoader loads same image multiple times

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am usiing UniversalImageLoader for loading images.But the problem I am facing is that same image is being loaded multiple times.Below is the log output.

Logcat:

```
11-11 11:10:21.342 26932-26932/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc D/ImageLoader: Load image from memory cache [http://loc8app.com/ktdcapp.in/ktdc/app/img/Aranya%20Nivas/room3.jpg_480x340]
11-11 11:10:21.342 26932-29175/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc D/ImageLoader: ImageAware is reused for another image. Task is cancelled. [http://loc8app.com/ktdcapp.in/ktdc/app/img/Aranya%20Nivas/room1.jpg_480x340]
11-11 11:10:21.342 26932-29175/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc D/ImageLoader: ImageAware is reused for another image. Task is cancelled. [http://loc8app.com/ktdcapp.in/ktdc/app/img/Aranya%20Nivas/room2.jpg_480x340]
```

MainActivity.java:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config=new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).memoryCacheExtraOptions(480,800).threadPoolSize(5).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-3).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().memoryCacheSize(2*104*1024).memoryCacheSizePercentage(13).diskCacheSize(50*1024*1024).diskCacheFileCount(100).imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(getApplicationContext())).defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()).writeDebugLogs().build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

HotelsFragment.java:

```
   DisplayImageOptions options=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
for(int i=0;i<Images.getInstance().AranyaGll.length;i++){
imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById((Integer) imgs_ids.get(i));
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Images.getInstance().AranyaGll[i],imageView,options);
 }
```

Comment: I think Image is not caching. you shold check for displayoption once. you can try by increasing cache size. Please have a look at this ->  https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Configuration

Comment: DiskCacheSize or memoryCacheSize?

Comment: The memory cache size was memoryCacheSize(2*104*1024).I changed it to  memoryCacheSize(2*1024*1024).Still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    for (int i = 0; i < Images.getInstance().AranyaGll.length; i++) {
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById((Integer) imgs_ids.get(i));
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Images.getInstance().AranyaGll[i], imageView, options);
    }
```

With this:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    for (int i = 0; i < Images.getInstance().AranyaGll.length; i++) {
        //This is the change I made.
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById((Integer) imgs_ids.get(i));
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Images.getInstance().AranyaGll[i], imageView, options);
    }
```

Note: I made the image view local